# Flaskr SyntaxError

Tags: python, web-frameworks, flask

I'm trying out the Flaskr tutorial(http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/) and I got the following error after I tried to run *flaskr.py* using the terminal:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I have absolutely no idea why I got this error. Can someone help me please?

Comment: could you add the original part of code related to this error please?

Comment: here it is- https://gist.github.com/887965

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have forgotten a closing parenthesis in your `return` line, above your `if __name__ == "__main__":` statement, you put

```
return redirect(url_for('show_entries')
```

and it should be

```
return redirect(url_for('show_entries'))
```

Comment: thanks but another error showed up- before_request() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)....

Comment: and in the tutorial its written- *before_request() takes now argument*

Comment: problem solved- spotted two brackets that shouldn't have been there. Thanks a lot!!